# Using append and document.write, slider run and doesnot run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use list_carousel slider to run posts with HTML like that :

```
    <div class="list_carousel">
       <div id='gallary'>
       <ul id='foo3'>
         <li>A</li>
         <li>B</li>
         <li>C</li>
       </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
```

I use document.write, slider run ok.

```
 <div class="list_carousel">
   <div id='gallary'>
    <script>
   document.write('<ul id="foo3">');
    document.write('<li>A</li>');
    document.write('<li>B</li>');
    document.write('<li>C</li>');
   document.write('<ul>');
     </script>
  </div>
 </div>
```

But when I use innerHTML, slider does not run :

```
<div class="list_carousel">
  <div id="gallary">
  </div>
 document.getElementById('gallary').innerHTML = " <ul id='foo3'>..... </ul>";
</div>
```

Slider run with call :

```
<script>
    $("#foo3").carouFredSel({
        auto: false,
        responsive: true,

        scroll: 1,
        mousewheel: true,
        items: {
            visible: 3,
            width: 200
        }
    });
</script>
```

Say me reason why and solution for this.

Comment: When you do `innerHTML` you are not assigning the `id` of `foo` to the `<ul>`, or did you just not show us that part?

Comment: sorry. it's mistake of my post

Comment: Is your `innerHTML` call wrapped in `<script></script>` in your code? Because it isn't here - that will just render as plain text.